# Designing local Intranet for 100 employees... I have my own server, is XAMPP a good fit?

Tags: windows-server-2008, xampp, intranet

Pretty straight forward... I have just setup a Windows Server 2008 r2 Virtual Machine that will host our company's Intranet. I use XAMPP locally but was wondering if using XAMPP on this new production server would cause any issues.

Sure, I could install each on my own, but XAMPP makes everything so easy and since it will strictly be viewable to anyone with access to our network (internal only)... what is the harm... if any?

Comment: If it's only for intranet use, you're probably are good to go and won't find any benefit setting it all up yourself. But the only production-ready WAMP I know of directly is a commercial one. Check some of the other WAMPs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs . I think there are 1 or 2 free ones that have recently started advertising production-readyness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the [XAMPP philosophy](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html#300):

> The philosophy behind XAMPP is to build an easy to install
>   distribution for developers to get into the world of Apache. To make
>   it convenient for developers XAMPP is configured with all features
>   turned on.  The default configuration is not good from a securtiy
>   point of view and it's not secure enough for a production environment
>   - please don't use XAMPP in such environment.

I would say that installing XAMPP on a production server is not a good idea, because all features are turned on and the default configuration is setted to be use by a local server.

You will almost never have any problem using XAMPP on a local server considering that it's just an easy way to installing/configure Mysql, Php, Perl and Apache. But you must to be sure of what you need to open in your configuration file, for a dev server.

You should so verify XAMPP configuration before.

But since LAMPP 0.9.5, XAMPP installation can be secured by calling »/opt/lampp/lampp security«.

I never test this secured installation.

Comment: Sounds good... guess I was trying to get away actually doing some work ;) THanks for the info and for the reference to XAMPP's philosophy!

Answer (score 1):

What makes those bundled packages great is they make a lot of assumptions which save time in the development process. This is also what makes the packages not a good idea for hosting a production instance. The out-of-the-box configuration can compromise security and performance, so it's important to understand the configuration options Apache, PHP, and MySQL even though it will take some time.

Answer (score -1):

Well, XAMPP is just a software that sets up an AMP (Apache, MySQL, PHP) environment for you. You won't have any problem with with setup as long as you know what your doing, that is, you should be able to configure Apache, MySQL and PHP to fit your needs. But usually, the default settings provided by XAMPP work just fine.